# How to change stm32 PLL parameters in uboot device tree?

Tags: c, embedded, linux-device-driver, u-boot, device-tree

I'm new to u-boot and I have a custom board based on the Waveshare CoreH7 board. my crystal(HSE) frequency is 8MHz and I want to have a 400MHZ core frequency using the PLL1. according to [this](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/master/doc/device-tree-bindings/clock/st%2Cstm32h7-rcc.txt) documentation I should add the below code to my board.dts file.

```
    rcc {
        vco1@58024430 {
            #clock-cells = <0>;
            compatible = "stm32,pll";
            reg = <0>;
            st,clock-div = <4>; // 8MHz divided by 4 = 2MHz
            st,clock-mult = <400>; // (2MHz * 400)/2 = 400MHz
            st,frac-status = <0>;
            st,frac = <0>;
            //st,vcosel = <1>;
            st,pllrge = <1>;
        };
    };
```

so, now my frequency should be 400MHz. but it's not!

I set the uboot logging level to 8 to see all logs. and after checking the output logs on the serial terminal, I realized that u-boot even won't care about those "vco1" parameters in my device tree. so I dicided to take a look at the rcc driver, and when I saw the code, I realized that pll parameters are defined in the driver itself, and the driver even won't care about those parameters that I wrote them in my device tree.
this is a part of [stm32h7 driver](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/master/drivers/clk/clk_stm32h7.c) at 329th line:

```
/*
 * OSC_HSE = 25 MHz
 * VCO = 500MHz
 * pll1_p = 250MHz / pll1_q = 250MHz pll1_r = 250Mhz
 */
struct pll_psc sys_pll_psc = {
    .divm = 4,
    .divn = 80,
    .divp = 2,
    .divq = 2,
    .divr = 2,
};
```

I can't understand what's happening here! As I know, the driver should read these parameters from device tree. So, if the user should write these parameters in the device tree, why the driver has these values in it when it can read them from device tree?

Comment: Most likely the u-boot code is less thoroughly dependent on device tree than the Linux kernel is.  Perhaps you can change that and submit a pr

Comment: @ChrisStratton thanks. but what do you mean by submitting a pr? what is pr?

Comment: Pull Request - basically contributing your change by inviting the repo owner to copy a commit from yours into theirs

Comment: @ChrisStratton so you mean I should make a change to this driver to force it to read the defined values in the device tree? Right? I can't understand well how the u-boot drivers read the device data from device trees. can you please provide me some tutorials or docs about how u-boot reads the device tree nodes properties?

Comment: These are the things you are going to have to figure out by studying the code - requests for help in finding external materials are explicitly off topic on stack exchange sites.   It's worth considering what your goal here is - Linux on the STM32H7 seems a bit dubious as more than a curiosity so perhaps not worth a lot of investment in making a beautifully consistent codebase, and if you're trying to get something to work just changing the values in the code may be the path of least resistance.